# Rails attribute_accessible allows mass assignment of attribs in 1 of 2 models with parallel construction. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

In a stripped down project to demonstrate the problem

**rake test yields:**

```
1) Failure:
test_can_mass_assign_accessible_flds(BrandTest) [ test/unit/brand_test.rb:11]:

Exception raised:
<#<ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:  \
    Can't mass-assign protected attributes: brand_name, support_num>>.

2 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

The two models and tests have parallel construction but yield different results when tested. Experience tells me this should be my error but I cannot see where. Can anyone help?

**Models:**

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :brand_name, :support_num, :comment
end

class Mask < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :brand_id, :brand_sku, :comment
end
```

**Tests:**

```
require 'test_helper'
class BrandTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @accessible_flds = { :brand_name => 'MyString', 
                         :support_num => 'MyString', 
                         :comment => 'MyText' }
  end

  test "can mass assign accessible flds" do
    assert_nothing_raised { Mask.new(@accessible_flds) }
  end
end

class MaskTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @accessible_flds = { :brand_id => 1, 
                         :brand_sku => 'MyString', 
                         :comment => 'MyText' }
  end

  test "can mass assign accessible flds" do
    assert_nothing_raised { Mask.new(@accessible_flds) }
  end
end
```

**Schema:**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20121212024505) do

  create_table "brands", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "brand_name"
    t.string "support_num"
    t.text   "comment"
  end

  create_table "masks", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "brand_id"
    t.string  "brand_sku"
    t.text    "comment"
  end

end
```

**Environment:**

```
Windows 7 Pro, SP 1
ruby -v  =>> ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [i386-mingw32]
rails -v =>> Rails 3.2.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `BrandTest` class is still referencing `Mask`:

```
Mask.new(@accessible_flds)
```

should be

```
Brand.new(@accessible_flds)
```